# R: Pulling data from one column to create new columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data with sample names that need to be unpacked and created into new columns.

```
sample
P10.1
P11.2
S1.1
S3.3
```

Using the sample ID data, I need to make three new columns: tissue, plant, stage.

```
sample tissue plant stage
P10.1  P      10    1
P11.2  P      11    2
S1.1   S      1     1
S3.3   S      3     3
```

Is there a way to pull the data from the sample column to populate the three new columns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

using `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

First we insert a "." in the sample code, next we separate sample into 3 columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(sample = paste0(substring(df$sample, 1, 1), ".", substring(df$sample, 2))) %>% 
  separate(sample, into = c("tissue", "plant", "stage"), remove = FALSE)

  sample tissue plant stage
1 P.10.1      P    10     1
2 P.11.2      P    11     2
3  S.1.1      S     1     1
4  S.3.3      S     3     3
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(sample = c("P10.1", "P11.2", "S1.1", "S3.3")), 
                .Names = "sample", 
                class = "data.frame", 
                row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @phiver, but uses regular expressions.

Within `pattern`:

- The first parentheses captures any single uppercase letter (for `tissue`)
- The second parentheses captures any one or two digit number (for `plant`)
- The third parentheses captures any one or two digit number (for `stage`)

The `sub()` function pulls out those capturing groups, and places then in new variables.

```
library(magrittr)
pattern <- "^([A-Z])(\\d{1,2})\\.(\\d{1,2})$"
df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    tissue   = sub(pattern, "\\1", sample),
    plant    = as.integer(sub(pattern, "\\2", sample)),
    stage    = as.integer(sub(pattern, "\\3", sample))
  )
```

Result (displayed with `str()`):

```
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ sample: chr  "P10.1" "P11.2" "S1.1" "S3.3"
 $ tissue: chr  "P" "P" "S" "S"
 $ plant : int  10 11 1 3
 $ stage : int  1 2 1 3
```

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to phiver's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474718/7669809), but use `separate` twice. Notice that we can specify the position index in the `sep` argument.

```
library(tidyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  separate(sample, into = c("tissue", "number"), sep = 1, remove = FALSE) %>%
  separate(number, into = c("plant", "stage"), sep = "\\.", remove = TRUE, convert = TRUE)
dat2
#   sample tissue plant stage
# 1  P10.1      P    10     1
# 2  P11.2      P    11     2
# 3   S1.1      S     1     1
# 4   S3.3      S     3     3
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "sample
P10.1
P11.2
S1.1
S3.3",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```